# How to build a bookdown book that is not in the top-level directory in RStudio?

Tags: r, bookdown

The [bookdown docs](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/usage.html) say after setting up `_bookdown.yml` appropriately,

> Then you can click the Build Book button in the Build pane in RStudio
>   to compile the Rmd files into a book

I see no "Build Book" button in my RStudio, even after restart.

```
> packageVersion('bookdown')
[1] ‘0.18’
```

Here is my `_bookdown.yml`:

```
rmd_files: ["one.Rmd", "two.Rmd", "three.Rmd"]
site: "bookdown::bookdown_site"
output:
  bookdown::gitbook:
    lib_dir: "book_assets"
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    keep_tex: yes
delete_merged_file: true
```

I wonder if it's because my `_bookdown.yml` and my `.Rmd` files are not in the top-level directory.  I want to make a book a week, so I have a subdirectory for each book.  I use the same top-level project, so I can share code among books.

So if I am correct about the subdirectory being the problem: how to build a bookdown book that is not in the top-level directory in RStudio?

Otherwise, is there something else I should check?

**EDIT**: I'm just working on a function to build the book instead, something like:

```
make_book <- function(subdir) {
  setwd(paste0('dir/',subdir))
  # note: input doesn't matter, because config_file will have the book
  bookdown::render_book(input='_bookdown.yml',
                        config_file='_bookdown.yml')
  setwd(here::here())
}
```

Comment: Using your function is the right way to do it. If you share some code between books, that would be a good idea to put everything in a R package. With your books in the 'inst' directory, rendered with bookdown::render_book(). Input would be the index.rmd path. A package would help avoid setwd()

Comment: If you submit that as an answer ("do it with a function"), I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend keeping this idea of the function.
Use this one instead:

```r
make_book <- function(subdir) { 

origwd <- setwd(file.path('dir', subdir))
on.exit(setwd(origwd))
 bookdown::render_book(input='_bookdown.yml', config_file='_bookdown.yml')
}
```